# Setting one side of an NSSplitView programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nssplitview

I've got an `NSSplitView` and on the left side I've got a tableView (like a source list) and depending on row selection, I want to change the the right side of the split view. I can't quite figure out how to do this.

When I add my desired subview to the splitview, it adds another split (so now there's 3 views total... not what I wanted).

```
[mySplitView addSubview:myCustomView];
```

How do I properly set the right side of my splitView?

**Update**

Using

```
[mySplitView replaceSubview:[[mySplitView subviews] objectAtIndex:1] withSubview:myCustomView]
```

Seems to work, however it's resizing the split view rather oddly, how can I stop this? In IB there's an option to turn off `autoResizesSubviews` but I can't uncheck this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the frame of your new view to that of the old view before performing the swap.

Comment: @JonF: 1. Get the frame of the old view. 2. Set the frame of the new view to that. 3. Then swap the old view for the new.

Comment: NSRect rect = [[[_splitView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] frame];
    [[_tableVC view] setFrame:rect];
    [_splitView replaceSubview:[[_splitView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] with:_tableVC.view];

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might take a look at [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) which provides a much nicer way to set the sizes for the sides of a split pane.

Comment: I've looked in to that before, and I'll probably eventually use it. For now I want to learn how to do things the `Hard way` so I can understand them better. I find when I start off with toolkits too much of it feels like magic. After I'm comfortable, I will likely use it though. I've heard nothing but good about it.